# multiple class selection targeting distinct children

Tags: jquery, css

try the following:

add two divs to a page with the same class name.
add two elements within each div: for argument's sake paragraphs.
make the text color of the first paragraph of each div red.

why can't i figure out how to do this relatively simple task without having to use id's?

Comment: I think no one can answer this question. How should *we* know why you can't figure it out? We, or at least I,  don't even know you. ( ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this in jQuery ([`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)):

```
$(".myClass > :first-child").css('color', 'red');
```

But CSS will do it as well ([CSS `:first-child` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child)), and you *should* use this route if possible :)

```
.myClass > :first-child { color: red; }
```

Comment: thanks nic. i had tried both selectors, but didn't think to use them in combination. my example is a bit simplistic - i need to do some manipulation first, so css wouldn't be the way to go in my situation.